# What would the Romans have called "sorcery"?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, religio

In Christian Latin, the word *maleficia* is used for "witchcraft" or "sorcery": supernatural powers that don't come from God, and are probably associated with demons. A person who uses these powers is a *maleficus* or a *malefica*. (For example, Exodus 22:18, *maleficōs non patieris vivere*: "you shall not allow sorcerers to live".)

I'm curious if the Romans had a similar conception: not of demons or Satanic pacts, but of barbarians doing unclean, uncivilized magicks that were an affront to Roman propriety. Is there a Classical word for this sort of "sorcery", or for someone who uses it?

(Off the top of my head, Lucan describes a grove sacred to strange, horrifying "old gods", and some blasphemous rituals to converse with the dead. But *necromantia* in and of itself isn't inherently uncivilized: Aeneas and Odysseus both talked to ghosts to divine the future. The sorcerous meaning of *maleficia* also seems to be post-classical: most of the examples of L&S use it to mean simply "doing harm".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Virgil uses *magicas artes* in Aeneid 4.493:

> Testor, cara, deos et te, germana, tuumque
>   dulce caput, magicas invitam accingier artes.

The adjective *[magicus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmagicus)* seems to be right in the semantic field you're looking for, and it has barbarian connotations baked into the [etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magi).